# Need to modify a batch file to be able to process non-ASCII filenames

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, character-encoding

I'm gonna say from the start that i've got no programming experience whatsoever.
Someone in an audio forum wrote this batch file for me in order to downsample WAV files using a Command Line program called FinalCD. Works perfect, but i noticed it cant process files with filenames in unicode, cyrillic, asian symbols etc.
Someone told me i can fix this but putting the filenames in doublequotes, by i couldnt figure out where exactly in the code.

```
echo off
cls
for %%a in ("input\*.wav") do finalcd /f0 /d1 "%%a" "output\%%~nxa"
pauseecho off
```

Also the person who wrote it said something about not including safety checks, i was just wondering if the safety checks means looking for errors during processing or checking for potential hidden malware before processing a file.

Comment: What is `finalcd`? Is it an executable with file extension `.exe` or `.com` or a script file with file extension `.bat` or `.cmd` or `.vbs`, ...? Does `finalcd` support Unicode file names at all? Try for the third line `for %%I in ("input\*.wav") do finalcd.exe /f0 /d1 "%%I" "output\%%~nxI" 2>nul || finalcd.exe /f0 /d1 "%%~sfI" "output\%%~snxI"` to run `finalcd` a second time if it exits with an exit value not equal 0 with using short 8.3 file names for input and output file. The first line should be `@echo off`.

Comment: The Windows command processor `cmd.exe` processing a batch file is not designed for processing Unicode file names. The usage of UTF-8 character encoding as done with `chcp 65001` is of course a not really working workaround for this limitation of `cmd.exe`. It would be best to run `finalcd` on a list of `.wav` files using PowerShell which is designed for working with Unicode file names, if `finalcd` itself supports Unicode file names at all.

Comment: finalcd is an executable, .exe. But i use the batch file to run it, and batch compress multiple files. There's a frontend too but it's very meager and allows only for single file processing. If it's actually capable itself is a good question. The dev said it's old visual C++ and to much work to input the support himself.
How would i go about running it in powershell?

Comment: From reading this i'm guessing if the software can't support it, i wont be able to change it on my end? I'm a software noob so i figured it'd be possible by changing the batch file

Comment: Well, if `finalcd.exe` does not support itself Unicode file names, it is possible to use PowerShell to process all `.wav` files in a loop which first renames the current file to process to `temp.wav`, runs `finalcd.exe` with `temp.wav` as input file name and `output\temp.wav` as output file name and PowerShell renames the input file back to original file name and renames also the output file name to the name of original name.

Comment: That sounds great, i'm gonna look into it!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off
chcp 65001
for %%a in ("input\*.wav") do finalcd /f0 /d1 "%%a" "output\%%~nxa"
pause
```

Comment: No still not, got the following errors (multiple files) _Active code page: 65001
FinalCD v0.29a - High Precision Resampler
(c)2004-21 Tom Browne / Sonic Illusions
Handle error!FinalCD v0.29a - High Precision Resampler
(c)2004-21 Tom Browne / Sonic Illusions
Failed to open input file input\fXxs - Apotheoptic - 04 ?????????.wav!
Conversion failed with error code -1_

Comment: Try with `chcp 437` to avoid automatic character conversions (though this may not solve issues with Unicode characters)…